# Can we give a desired direction to the electric field by connecting the wires to one terminal having some potential?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage

Let's say we have a battery and one wire is connected to the one terminal having let's say some positive potential and other end of the wire is connected to the plate which is from one side it is metallic and the other side is made of a material which have a larger dielectric constant so that it should not create electric fields on the backside from where the wire is connected to the plate.

[image]

(refer the diagram created by me for better visualization)

And when we direct that one end of the wire having the metallic plate towards one direction will it create the electric field in that direction? (wire will also be on positive potential because it's connected to the terminal having positive potential).

In other words let's say I want to create an electric field in the left direction and I face that metallic plate towards left direction will I get the electric field originating from the plate in the left direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Firstly, unless the *other* terminal of the battery is connected to a large conductor or grounding surface, the field produced by the plate would be very weak, with a magnitude comparable to that of the local field generated by the battery itself (which usually can be approximated as a dipole.)  The only configuration in which the plate would generate any broadly appreciable field whatsoever* would be if the plate were situated close to the presumably comparably small negative terminal, which would allow it to act as a capacitor.

Within a reasonably small neighborhood of the charged plate (i.e. of order the plate diameter), the magnitude of the field is larger along the vector normal to the exposed metallic surface.  At larger separations, however, the field first approaches an isotropic regime with roughly equal magnitude in all directions (assuming that object is far from the battery), and then a dipolar limit as either the battery or (at even larger scales) the ground object comes into view. In any event, it's probably safe to say, barring exceptional arrangements of the battery and/or orientations of the plate with respect to the grounding surface, that the field will never vanish in the region/direction of interest.

The lower field magnitude on the side of the the plate facing the dielectric can be understood as arising from induced dipole moments in the dielectric medium, or (anticipating that the dielectric will tend to suppress field strength) in terms of Gauss' law and/or continuity.

Footnotes:

*With the possible exception of sensing applications

Comment: "At larger separations, however, the field first approaches an isotropic regime" . I didn't understand what are you actually trying to say here. And I would like to ask that is it possible to charge the plate by connecting plate to the positive potential (positive terminal) of the battery?

Comment: The battery effectively imposes a potential difference between its terminals and whatever conducting elements are attached to them (and possibly through those elements when they connect to both terminals.)  Connecting the plate to one terminal of the battery will *generically* influence its charge (unless you charged it earlier under the same conditions) but the effect is rather weak if the background field (i.e. the field without the battery or plate) is zero.  This is because the battery itself generates an ambient potential through free space (usually a dipole)...

Comment: ... and the far field strength of the dipole or quadrupole or higher can usually be lessened by redistributing charge between available conductors in some way.  You could also imagine the battery as a sort of non-linear capacitor (with a V(Q) curve instead of a simple line, that becomes very flat near full capacity) between the two leads, and the additional conducting plate as a sort of linear capacitor in parallel, with a capacitance that depends on how far the plate is from the opposite lead.

Comment: @TejasDahake Also, thanks for the question; it helped me notice a way to improve my answer.